# how to edit data in html form after retrieving it from database

Tags: html, forms, jsp

i have created and added data into database through jsp.Now my problem is with edit/update the database which should be done through html form.In one for i select student rollno and form should display all other fields and then i can edit it and update the database.

editcourse.jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>

        <link href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/default.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="sidebarmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <script src="sidebarmenu.js"></script>
                <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script> 

</head>
    <body>  

        <!--<form id="frmExamRegistration" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="anu">-->


    <form name="f1" method="post" class="anu" action="Edit_coursedetails.jsp">  
    <%@include file="adminheader.jsp"%>
<%@include file="sidemenus.jsp" %>

    <div id="container">
              <div  style="float:right;width:10%;border:0;font-color:#163362"><a href=logout.jsp">Log Out</a></div><br>
        <div class="content"><center>Edit Course</center><br>
            <div class="formElements,rightcol" align="center">
                <label>Course code:
                 <span><input type="text" id="txtCoursecode" name="txtCoursecode" ></span></label>
                       </div><br>



            <div class="buttons">
                <button type="submit" class="primaryAction">Edit</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="primaryAction">Clear</button>

            </div>
                 </div>
         </div>
       </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

edit_coursedetails.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>

        <link href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/default.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="sidebarmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <script src="sidebarmenu.js"></script>
                <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script> 

</head>
    <body>  

        <!--<form id="frmExamRegistration" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="anu">-->




                       <%
 ccode=request.getParameter("txtCoursecode");


try {


Statement st = null;
st=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from courses where course='"+txtCoursecode+"'");
if(rs.next())
{
cname=rs.getString("cname");
Description=rs.getString("Description");
}
%>
Edit courses

<form name="f1" method="post" class="anu" action="Add_coursedetails.jsp">  
    <%@include file="adminheader.jsp"%>
<%@include file="sidemenus.jsp" %>

    <div id="container">
              <div  style="float:right;width:10%;border:0;font-color:#163362"><a href=logout.jsp">Log Out</a></div><br>
        <div class="content"><center>Add Course</center><br>

            <div class="formElements,rightcol" align="center">

                <label>Course code:
                 <span><input type="text" id="txtCoursecode" name="txtCoursecode" value="<%=rs.ccode%>"></span></label>
                       </div><br>

            <div class="formElements,rightcol" align="center">
                <label>Course Name:
                 <span><input type="text" id="txtCoursename" name="txtCoursename" value="<%=rs.cname%>"></span></label>
                        </div><br>

                        <div class="formElements,rightcol" align="center">
                <label>Duration:
                 <span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;<input type="text" id="txtDuration" name="txtDuration" value="<%=rs.getString("3")%>"></span></label>
                        </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button type="submit" class="primaryAction">Update</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="primaryAction">Clear</button>

            </div>
                 </div>
         </div>
<%
}
}
catch(Exception e){}
%>
       </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

in editcourse form by giving ccode it should display all other field from database with thier value and then i can modify it

Comment: which data you need to edit mode?

Comment: try same Ajax to edit and update the data.....

Comment: @Ravi by giving rollno it should display all other details of student and i need t edit that data

Comment: @RajMohan i dont know Ajax

Comment: add some your layout image .

Comment: I'm agree with "Ravi", please provide us with some screenshots, because it's not clear that which part of the form should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either ajax or give url of jsp in form action attribute.
then in that jsp get txtRollno from request, retrieve fields from database for this rollno, populate data into appropriate field and then you can edit it and then update into database.

Answer (score 0):

As other friends said you need to use ajax call and you said that you don't know ajax.
So I think these tutorials help you:

1) [What is AJAX?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/534632/WhatplusisplusAJAX-3f)

2) [AJAX Example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp)

3) [jQuery Ajax call tutorial](http://www.cleverweb.nl/php/jquery-ajax-call-tutorial/)

Good Luck ;)

Comment: i am posting my code for edit.could you please tell where i went wrong